# Generate XML file in C# with XSD file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-serialization

I am trying to build a new XML file with C# using an existing XSD file. 
this is the xsd file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="KilometerUpload">
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="KilometerRegistration">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="ChassisNumber">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="17" />
                                <xsd:minLength value="1" />
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="KilometerStatus">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="7" />
                                <xsd:minLength value="1" />
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="TypeOfData">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="3" />
                                <xsd:minLength value="1" />
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="ObservationDate">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>Format: yyyyMMdd</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="8" />
                                <xsd:minLength value="8" />
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="LegallyResponsible">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="10" />
                                <xsd:minLength value="10" />
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="EnteredBy">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="10" />
                                <xsd:minLength value="10" />
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="InternalCode">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="10" />
                                <xsd:minLength value="0" />
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="DateFirstRegistration">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>Format: yyyyMMdd</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="8" />
                                <xsd:minLength value="0" />
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Unifier">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="2" />
                                <xsd:minLength value="0" />
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="FeedbackType" type="FeedbackType" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="FeedbackEmail" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:simpleType name="FeedbackType">
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>The feedback type for this file</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="FTP" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="EML" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="DEF" />
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I have done the following things to create the XML file :

- made a class with xsd.exe
- I added the class to my project
- wrote the following function :

  ```
                  var data = new KilometerUploadKilometerRegistration 
              {
              ChassisNumber = huidigefactuur.Wagen.Chassisnummer,
              KilometerStatus = huidigefactuur.KMStand.ToString(),
              TypeOfData = "120",

              };
              var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KilometerUploadKilometerRegistration));
              using (var stream = new StreamWriter("C:\\test.xml"))
                  serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
  ```

It's working to create the XML file but I need to start at KilometerUpload node and than the KilometerRegistration node how do I do this?

This is the output i get with the code I used above :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<KilometerUploadKilometerRegistration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<ChassisNumber>WVWZZZ3CZ7E201402</ChassisNumber>

<KilometerStatus>78000</KilometerStatus>

<TypeOfData>120</TypeOfData>

</KilometerUploadKilometerRegistration>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer :

- I did not need to change my class generated by the xsd.exe

This is the code I ended with, it works perfectly now :

```
                foreach (Factuur huidigeFactuur2 in e.SelectedObjects)
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KilometerUpload));
                TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test2.xml");

                string chassisnummer = huidigeFactuur2.Wagen.Chassisnummer;
                string kilometerstatus = huidigeFactuur2.KMStand.ToString();

                KilometerUpload item = new KilometerUpload
                {
                    KilometerRegistration = new KilometerUploadKilometerRegistration[] { new KilometerUploadKilometerRegistration{ ChassisNumber = chassisnummer , TypeOfData = "120", KilometerStatus = kilometerstatus} },
                };

                serializer2.Serialize(writer, item);
```

Answer (score 1):

your serialiser is at `KilometerUpdateKilometerRegistration` have you tried to set that at

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(kilometerUpload));
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet. Can the serializer be different from the var data?

Comment: I have tried to set the serializer at Kilometerupload but when i run it I get this error : "There was an error generating the XML document"

Answer (score 0):

to write an xml file you can use XmlWriter class.

here is a tutorial

http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter

Comment: Isn't there a shorter way using the XML serializatin? I allready generated an xml file with this short piece of code but I need different nodes

Comment: I updated my question with the output my code now generates. As you can see my starting node is the KilometerUpdateKilometerRegistration this is not what I want my first node needs to be kilometerUpload and the second node is KilometerRegistration

Answer (score 0):

Building an xml from xsd in code will be tiresome. In the past I have used the [XMLSampleGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx) by Priya Lakshminarayanan. The sourcecode to this particular project is found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=31609).

I needed to do pretty much what you wanted, but the sample generation of visual studio was not sufficient. The XmlSampleGenerator I provided a link to is similar to the VS sample generation, but obviously you have the source code, and as such you can debug and adjust it to your needs (in my case I needed proper sample regex expression generation).

A word of warning: Generating xmls from a xsd is no easy task, so dont expect it to be. Good luck.

**Edit:** This code will generate an Xml that also contains a KilometerUpload Node.

```
namespace XmlGen {
public class Program {
    private static void Main( string[] args ) {

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlItem));
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\hasch\Downloads\test.xml");
        XmlItem item = new XmlItem();
        serializer.Serialize(writer,item);
    }
}



public class XmlItem {

    public KilometerUpload KilometerUpload;

    public KilometerRegistration KilometerRegistration;
    
    public XmlItem() {
        KilometerUpload = new KilometerUpload();
        KilometerRegistration = new KilometerRegistration();
    }
}

public class KilometerUpload {


}

public class KilometerRegistration {

    public string ChassisNumber { get; set; }

    public string KilometerStatus { get; set; }

    public string TypeOfData { get; set; }

    public KilometerRegistration() {
        ChassisNumber = "WVWZZZ3CZ7E201402";

        KilometerStatus = "78000";

        TypeOfData = "120";

    }}}
```

And this is the generated Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <XmlItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >                    
<KilometerUpload />
 <KilometerRegistration>
  <ChassisNumber>WVWZZZ3CZ7E201402</ChassisNumber>
   <KilometerStatus>78000</KilometerStatus>
  <TypeOfData>120</TypeOfData>
</KilometerRegistration>
```

Do keep in mind that this is in fact NOT generating xml from an xsd! If your xsd changes you will have to make major changes to your classes and such.

Comment: I think I am really close , I only need 1 more node to the XML file and it's completed. But I just dont know how to split the KilometerUpdateKilometerRegistration node into 2.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you want the KilometerUpdateKilometerRegistration do be present two times? Like with different data? Or do you mean a subnode is missing (e.g. ObservationDate)? Are you using the XmlSerializer solution you posted above?

Comment: Yes I am using the XMLSerializer I stated above. The problem is now i have 1 node : KilometerUpdateKilometerRegistration . I need 2 nodes first KilometerUpdate than Kilometerregistration like in my XSD file.

Comment: Added sample code. Is this helpful? Btw, its "then" not "than", but lots german speaking people make that mistake ;) Mahlzeit!

Comment: Thanks for the example ! I know if my XSD changes I will have to change the class, but this XSD file hasn't changed in years. I noticed that you initialise the properties inside a class but I'm trying to generate the XML file through a method that is not in that class. The data that fills the XML file comes from a different class that's why i use a different method

Comment: Glad to help. The solution i provided was a draft, so feel free to change it to fit your needs. I'd appreciate it if you would accept my answer (if it did help you solve your problem!)

Comment: To use this solution I have to change my class? This class was generated by the xsd.exe tool that VS delivers. Can't I do this without changing the class?

Comment: You dont need to change your class. The only problem is, that Xsd.exe does not generate a class for the simple type KilometerUpload. You only need to add this as a class if you want it to be added to your xml. Since you mentioned the xsd doesnt actually change that shouldnt be a problem. To avoid a comment discussion i suggest you play around with xml serializer to get a feel for what gets mapped and how. I'm afraid i cannot help you any further. Good luck!

Comment: Oke thanks for the help !! I understand it way better now ! I have accepted your answer, thanks again !

Comment: I noticed something about your class. the class begins with the node XMLItem, mine begins with KilometerUpload so I don't need to add the class it's allready there but as the XMLItem you implemented so this is not quite the solution I was looking for. Could you help me a bit more?